# Sync MIB-files without folders tree (for snmp)

Tags: svn, subdirectory, mib, snmpd

We have an svn-repo with some mib-files. For humans it is usable to keep files in subfolders:

```
MIBS
 +VendorA
   +MIB1.txt
   +MIB2.txt
 +VendorB
   +MibN.txt
...
```

Users can update or add MIBs with Tortoise clients. Servers should update their working copies themselves by cron.

But snmpd does not support subdirectories, from man-page:

> **/usr/local/share/snmp/mibs/**
>
> The agent will also load all files in this directory as MIBs.
>   It will not, however, load any file that begins with a '.' or descend
>   into subdirectories.

Is it possible to sync files from repo without containing  folders?

Thanks for any feedback!

Answer (score 0):

[SVN externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html) of file-type + hand-work. I.e

- Create in the same repo special checkout-only folder (outside /trunk, probably)
- Map every "virtual" file inside folder to real file in MIBs-tree
- Maintain link-list in actual state (new MIBs must be added to definition, deleted - removed) - probably can be automated by post-commit hook
- SVN-users with flat-MIBs requirement have to checkout URL of FLAT folder

Comment: Seems to be helpful.. I will try this solution and comment result after